# How to find database owned project on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm receiving errors from a service, that consumes a MySQL database on GCP, but, I can't find the right project there.

I have the MySQL server IP, database name, user and password set up on heroku (the consumer), but I'm unable to locate the GCP project where it was created.

**How to find the project, by the IP and database name? Is it possible?**

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to gcloud and have viewer role privileges here is a bash script for you :

```
 #!/bin/bash -e

PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list --format="value(project_id)" | sort | uniq)
echo $PROJECTS
myip='[yourip]'
# use this two line if you already have the list of projectsid
# PROJECTS=(projectid1 projectid2 projectid3)
#for project in ${PROJECTS[@]};
for project in PROJECTS;
do
        for line in $(gcloud compute instances list --project $project --format="value(NAME,INTERNAL_IP)") # change value of INTERNAL_IP to EXTERNAL_IP if your ip is external
        do
                if [[ "$line" == "$myip" ]]; then
                        echo $project
                fi
        done
done
```